# Inline JS, how to escape a quote in a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, quotes

Is this a bug within JavaScript? http://jsfiddle.net/SommerEngineering/mr8sZ/

```
<a href='javascript:test("test")'>Works</a><br/>
<a href='javascript:test("test&quot;")'>Does not work</a>
```

Its looks like JS goes into the string, converts back the `&quot;` into `"` and then tries to execute the command, which is then of course wrong.

Comment: That's not JS related at all. That's a HTML entity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct. What you're writing there is html, so the html entity `&quote;` is rendered as a double quote `"`, then executed as JavaScript. Because `test("test"");` is not valid javascript, this will throw an error. If you want to pass `test"` into the function, you would escape the quote like this: `test("test\"");`

Inline JavaScript is not a good practice and has tons of non-intuitive issues. Read some of these results: **[Why is inline JS bad?](https://www.google.com/search?q=Why%20is%20inline%20js%20bad?)**

Here's an example of how to do this properly.

```
var a = document.getElementById('myElem');

a.addEventListener('click', function() {
  test('test"');
});
```

Just note there are many ways to get element references and you might want to use a class and attach the handler within a loop.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a bug. The double quotes work because the HTML attribute has single quotes. However, the `&quot;` entity is evaluated by HTML, so the data passed to the JavaScript engine is:

```
javascript:test("test"")
```

If you want to escape the quotes use

```
javascript:test("test\"")
```

as a `\` escapes the quote.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a js bug, indeed it's an html behavior. The `&quot;` is an html entity that gets decoded to `"` prior to js execution.

Anyway, avoid to have embedded js in html, it's not a good practice, your case is one reason.